# Is it possible to change apps icons in share dialog using createChooser?

Tags: android

I use `createChooser()` to allow user to share photo. When user clicks Share button, dialog with applications appears. What I want is to have a dialog with installed applications to share (like Gmail, BT, Email, Facebook, etc) but with my custom icons.

Is it possible to change those applications icons and set my own icons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Only by making your own chooser, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to get the available options, and rendering the results how you wish.